# Tricklevent on narrow uPVC windows?

Tags: windows, ventilation, uk, humidity

I have some condensation issues inside a few bedrooms in my house, and I want to install trickle vents on the existing uPVC windows. They are old (20+ years), and I am hoping to get a few more years out of them before replacing. The frame is very narrow, at only 4cm wide. I know that trickle vents can be installed on wider frames, but I'm curious to know if there is a minimum size, is there any chance I'd hit the glass when drilling through?

Can I still install these vents on my windows?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I'm installing a PIV, and need trickle vents to ensure that I'm getting proper ventilation in each of the rooms affected, not just the one room with an existing trickle vent.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. What, exactly, is a "tricklevent", or is it "trickle vent", or "trickl event" :) ? Your use of metric measurements indicates you're likely not in the US. The US certainly isn't the whole world, but a good number of people who answer are US based, so that would help out. Please [edit] your post to define it. Once you've done that, please take the [tour] so you can get a feel for the place and get the most out of this site.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome Freeman. Yes, it's a trickle vent, but I like the idea of a trickl event! I'm based in the UK, and out here a lot of windows have vents on them to remove condensation from the inside of the house. You can see one being installed here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=132&v=DlGoG2CdLAk&feature=emb_title

Comment: I certainly don't have an answer for you, but that clarification will help. I'm pretty sure _someone_ will be along with a pretty reasonable answer for you (or more questions...)

Comment: I doubt if there is a standard, especially for a 20 year old window.  I know modern ones have rigid standards in NZ.  For strength of the uPVC holding the glass, I would say that 2cm from the edge would be maximum.  But thats a guess.  If you go slowly with a finest drill bit, at low speed on a window, maybe you can detect the glass without breaking it.   You take your life in your own hands.

Comment: @RohitGupta: ... Or at least your budget.